# Adding two variables in PHP not returning answer

Tags: php

I have a piece of code adding two variables already declared inside a function call. Like so:

```
my_function($var1 + $var2)
```

For some reason, when the output of this function is echoed to the created output page, the function raises an error saying the second variable is not declared. Both variables are definitely declared beforehand.

I have noticed that if I add the two variables before the function call then it works fine.

```
$total = $var1 + $var2;
echo my_function($total); // <-- This line outputs the result of the function correctly
```

Why does this happen? Is there a syntax rule in PHP I am unaware of?

Comment: [Works as expected](http://3v4l.org/Vq58P). Please share more/all of your code.

Comment: Can we have a look at the function? Is it anonymous or is the `$` in front a typo?

Comment: it depends on what version you are eusing

Comment: Thought it was related to closures somehow, but this also works http://3v4l.org/Lb8EW

Comment: Oh hangon, do you mean it is saying that `$var2` is not declared?

Comment: The $ before my_function was a typo. I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your presumption is wrong... the declaration of the function is with only one variable, not 2 and that is why the error is thrown... This depends on the PHP version that you use :D

You should do one of the following: (Because these are considered "good practice")

1. As you already did it with

   `$total = $var1 + $var2;
    echo my_function($total);`
2. placing the actual total in the function like:

   `funtion my_function($var1, $var2) {`

   `$total = $var1 + $var2;`

   `return $total;`

   `}`

   `echo my_function($var1, $var2);`

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: he discussing about can we send $var1 + $var2 instead of $total; while calling function. And your answer doesn't explain that. I think.

Comment: I think because in his second example it worked with only one parameter, implying that your solution doesn't address the issue.

Comment: @NaincyGupta the first part of my answer addresses that

Comment: Not my downvote, but your answer implies more knowledge about the real problem than can reasonably be guessed. Simply because what the OT states can not be true, as such the real problem could be anything. Such answers are downvoted often.

Comment: Yes. Putting the addition of two variables is something I expect to equate to sending another variable already adding the two variables. Changing this to a function with two input variables doesnt really address the question. The question is specifically about the addition not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like as following:

```
function my_function($var1, $var2)
{
return $var1+$var2;
}
echo my_function($var1,$var2);
```

Answer (score -2):

Please see note added by Yosii.

I just added that content here in my answer.

```
function foo($n) {
  return $n;
}

echo foo($a + $b), PHP_EOL;    
echo foo($c);
```

Output for 4.3.10 - 4.4.9, 5.0.2 - 5.6.2

```
3
3
```

Output for 4.3.0 - 4.3.9, 5.0.0 - 5.0.1

```
3
Notice: Use of undefined constant PHP_EOL - assumed 'PHP_EOL' in /in/Vq58P on line 10
PHP_EOL3
```

Reference: http://3v4l.org/Vq58P

Comment: as people not seeing it. I added that content here. also given reference of Yoshi. I don't take anyone's credit. @Flosculus